# Confusion optimal control abuse notation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, parabolic-pde, notation

I'm currently reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4503.pdf) describing a numerical scheme for the approximating optimal policy of a stochastic control problem.  However, I run into a confusion directly on the first page where there seems to be a "common abuse of notation".

The author write the [stochastic control problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_control#Continuous_time) determined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
v(t,x)= & sup_{a \in \mathcal{A}} \, \mathbb{E}^{t,x}\left[
\int_t^T f(X_s^a,a_s)ds + g(X_T^a)
\right]\qquad 0\leq t< T
\\
dX_t^a =&  b(X_s^a,a_s)dt + \sigma(X_s^a,a_s)dW_s,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathscr{A}$ a non-empty set of $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^q$-valued controls.

They state that the value function for this problem satisfies the [HJB equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation) written:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t v + \sup_{a \in A}\left[
b(x,a).D_xv 
+ \frac1{2}\operatorname{tr}(\sigma\sigma^T(x,a)D_x^2v)
+ f(x,a,v,\sigma^T(x,a).D_xv)
\right] = & 0 \qquad (t,x)\in [0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^d\\
v(T,x)= & g(x) \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}^d.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Problem:**
My problem is that $f$ is used to denote two different functions?  So how is f defined in the HJB equation (given that I know how to define it in the control problem) then?

Comment: Agree it is horrible notation. f is still the same f, but now implicitly depends on $\sigma$, $v$,and its gradient because the $a$ is taken to be  $a(x,v,\nabla v,\Delta v,\sigma)$. See these notes e.g.: http://www.columbia.edu/~dl3133/MFGSpring2018.pdf pages 63-70. In other words, $f=f(x,a(x,v,\nabla v,\Delta v,\sigma))$

Comment: In other words if my control doesn't depend on the value function explicitly then those terms may be ommited?  Ex if it is constant?

Comment: Well, the optimality condition gives you HJB, where the Hamiltonian term (see notes I linked to) is maximized over all possible controls, i.e., to do the sup, you have to allow control to have arbitary dependence on $v,x,\sigma$.. So you cannot prescribe the optimal control to be constant: it comes out of the maximization (sup ) process. Now depending upon the system, it may depend just on $\nabla v$, .e.g., in linear quadratic case (example given in the paper you mention), and yes, then you can omit other terms